# Is there a way to load every image in images.xcassets into a uicollectionview without manually typing the image name?

Tags: ios, swift

I want my users to be able to view every image that i have in images.xcassets in a collection view, but theres about 50 image, and I'd rather not manually type the name for every one. Is there a way that I can load them all without doing this?

Comment: Add them to a folder in your resources

Answer (score 2):

its not possible according the this [post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/968859#968859:)

> Unfortunately it is not possible to load images from any car file
>   aside from the one that Xcode compiles into your main bundle, as
>   +imageNamed: does not accept a bundle parameter, which is what is needed to do so (and even then it would only be able to open a single
>   asset catalog in a single bundle).

but there is always some solutions(today we have 2).

rename all images in your `images.xcassets` (lets say you have 20 message) to 0..19 and after that take image using loop like so:

```
    var imageList = [UIImage]()
    for i in 0 ..< 20{
        imageList.append(UIImage(named: String(i))!)
    }
//imageList will hold all your images
```

or you can put your images inside your project folder and search for file that contain the known images types like so:

```
let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!
let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path)
var imageList = [UIImage]()
for item in items {
    if item.hasSuffix("png") || item.hasSuffix("jpg") || item.hasSuffix("jpeg") {
        imageList.append(UIImage(named: item)!)
    }
}
```

**let me know if you need more explanation**